# How to handle empty array data in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

A simple question in Vue.js. In this code, the second "project" don't have any "Property", obviously no "Number", this make the html shows blank, how to handle this when there's no data in the array? I've tried v-if but can't make it work. Thanks

```
<div v-for="propiedad in info" class="propiedad">
   <div class="propiedad">
       {{ project.Property[0].Number }}
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What `v-if` did you try? Where does `project` come from and what sort of data is in it? What does it have to do with `info` or `propiedad`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take the question "this make the HTML shows blank" as "There is some errors in the console and the entire page fails."

You can do it by
`project && project.Property[0] && project.Property[0].Number`

Or if you are working with babel with plugin [babel-preset-env](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env), you can take advantage of the [optional chaining](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) feature

`project?.Property[0]?.Number`

Answer (score 0):

First, this looks off because of the loop that you are not using. (Is there a mistake or why bother showing it?)

A `v-if` should work, but it often gets verbose.

```
<div class="propiedad" v-if="project.Property && project.Property.length > 0 && project.Property[0].Number>
```

That should cover all the bases.

Therefore it's often cleaner to massage the data beforehand. Maybe make all projects have defaults.project.Property, so you don't have to check if it exists.

Or just make computed properties so your template can look nice

```
computed: {
     hasProperty(){
        return this.project.Property 
          && this.project.Property.length > 0 
          && this.project.Property[0].Number
     }
}

<div class="propiedad" v-if="hasProperty"> ... </div>
```

Or if this is indeed related to the loop . Make a computed array that filters the array.

```
computed: {
   // Here I make the wild assumption that info are actually projects
   // (just to make the loop relevant)
   filtered(){
     // Skip all the projects without "Properties".
     return this.info.filter( i => i.Property.length > 0 )
   }
}

<div v-for="propiedad in filtered"> ....
```